# Vite preview is working but I can not see it running when opening index.html

Tags: javascript, html, es6-modules, vite

I dont know if I'm doint it wrong here, but I started a vanilla.js project with vite, I did my code, and everything is working with: `npm run dev` (which runs `vite` command).

But when I run `npm run build` and I open `/dist/index.html` the page is not working.

Probably I'm doing something wrong.

I know that when I run `npm run build && npm run preview` it works. But I'm trying to make it work by only opening the `index.html` file, because AFAIK, that's the only way I could host it on Github pages.

Comment: You need a server to serve the `index.html`. That's what `npm run preview` does for you. You don't need to be able to open your `index.html` without a server for it to run on GitHub pages.

Comment: Thanks @tony19. I was missing the vite.config file.. Now its working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this at `vite.config.js` and now it works!

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
  base: '/roulette-simulation/'
});
```

Answer (score 8):

I added this on my `vite.config.js`.

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
  base: './'
});
```

It happens becouse our navigator doesnt recognize the path `/heres-the-file-or-paths` so i needed to add the `./` at the beginning of our path when are importing `.js` and `.css` files. The same for icons and others.

This makes that the build process ends with and `index.html` like this with our imports paths working. `href="./the-rest-of-the-path-here"`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="./vite.svg" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Vite + React</title>
        <script type="module" crossorigin src="./assets/index.b3824f6c.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/index.3fce1f81.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation about how it is different than the accepted own-answer.

Comment: I tryed the accepted own-answer, but it doesnt workt to me. Testing by myself adding `base` prop to the vite.config file i mannaged to get this solution. i had to add the specific base path `./` becouse adding something like `/testing-folder/` or `/` i kept getting the same error `cannot found the module index.something.js` what was in the assets folder after the build.